# Clang outputting garbage labels when given target x86_64-windows

Tags: c, clang

I am cross compiling a program on Mac for Windows using clang, and my assembling step is failing due to clang outputting weird labels on compilation.

Given the input file:

```
int main(void) {
    const char *msg = "test";
    return 0;
}
```

and compiled to the host with the command `clang test.c -S` gives a good assembly output which is

```
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .build_version macos, 11, 0
    .globl  _main                           ## -- Begin function main
    .p2align    4, 0x90
_main:                                  ## @main
    .cfi_startproc
## %bb.0:                               ## %entry
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rcx
    movq    %rcx, -16(%rbp)
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc
                                        ## -- End function
    .section    __TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals
L_.str:                                 ## @.str
    .asciz  "test"

.subsections_via_symbols
```

However, cross compiling with `clang test.c -S -target x86_64-windows` produces nearly the same output, except that the label for the string constant is garbage. The output exactly is

```
    .text
    .def     @feat.00;
    .scl    3;
    .type   0;
    .endef
    .globl  @feat.00
.set @feat.00, 0
    .file   "test.c"
    .def     main;
    .scl    2;
    .type   32;
    .endef
    .globl  main                            # -- Begin function main
    .p2align    4, 0x90
main:                                   # @main
.seh_proc main
# %bb.0:                                # %entry
    subq    $16, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 16
    .seh_endprologue
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movl    $0, 12(%rsp)
    leaq    "??_C@_04CEJDCDCH@test?$AA@"(%rip), %rcx
    movq    %rcx, (%rsp)
    addq    $16, %rsp
    retq
    .seh_handlerdata
    .text
    .seh_endproc
                                        # -- End function
    .section    .rdata,"dr",discard,"??_C@_04CEJDCDCH@test?$AA@"
    .globl  "??_C@_04CEJDCDCH@test?$AA@"    # @"??_C@_04CEJDCDCH@test?$AA@"
"??_C@_04CEJDCDCH@test?$AA@":
    .asciz  "test"

    .addrsig
```

These strange labels cause my assembler to fail with the error

```
Error: invalid character '?' in operand 1
```

Is there a way to switch to the normal labels that the not cross compilation outputs?

Note that while I am on Mac I am not using the Xcode `clang`, but rather a `clang` build from the source. Running `clang --version` gives:

```
clang version 11.0.0
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: When building for Windows, Clang can operate either in MSVC-compatible mode, or in MinGW/GCC compatible mode (and it needs an installation of the corresponding compiler to function properly). It seems you got the MSVC mode, which you can confirm by doing `clang --target x86_64-windows --version` printing `x86_64-unknown-windows-msvc`. You probably want the MinGW mode, so you should be using `--target x86_64-w64-windows-gnu`. You'll also have to point it to a MinGW installation using `--sysroot`. Also you shouldn't have to manually invoke the assembler, setting those two flags should be enough.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That was it exactly, if you want to make an answer I'll accept it. As for the manual assembling, my build system is strange due to a variety of circumstances so I actually assembling using `gas`.

Comment: I didn't figure out what exactly is going on in the assembly or why it's different, and I don't want to write a short answer that just says to use the flag. I'll leave it to you (if you want to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer originally posted in comments by HolyBlackCat:

> When building for Windows, Clang can operate either in MSVC-compatible mode, or in MinGW/GCC compatible mode (and it needs an installation of the corresponding compiler to function properly). It seems you got the MSVC mode, which you can confirm by doing `clang --target x86_64-windows --version` printing `x86_64-unknown-windows-msvc`. You probably want the MinGW mode, so you should be using `--target x86_64-w64-windows-gnu.` You'll also have to point it to a MinGW installation using `--sysroot`. Also you shouldn't have to manually invoke the assembler, setting those two flags should be enough.